# Include existing source from Eclipse into Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to setup a project in Android Studio which includes several source files from an Eclipse project.
The Eclipse project has the following structure:

- Library Project
- It has a reference to several folders with java classes in them (included by link source)

Now I'd like to have these resources in my project/module in Android Studio too, but I can't find any possibility to achieve this other than copying them directly.
I'd like to avoid this because these files are part of a self written Java framework which is used in combination with GWT too. So copying these files instead of linking them means all changes have to be done twice.

Is it possible to include these sources similar to link source from Eclipse or is there another solution?

Comment: What libraries are you using? I would use the gradle structure to include these libraries.

Comment: @hopeman: I updated my text. It's not a library, the framework is self written, so I have all the Java files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build your Eclipse project and reference it as a library in Android studio project. Then you would be able to access/use the required classes in the Android studio project.

Comment: That would be possible, but so I have to change the code in Eclipse, build it an check if it works in Android Studio. That would be very cumbersome.

Comment: After some more investigation, this seems to be the best solution. Unfortunately, the IntelliJ possibilities to include external sources aren't available in Android Studio. So I'll check your answer. Thanks for your help.